# I encountered an error while sending mail, using ActionMailer within anI18n environment

Tags: rails-i18n, mailer

My User class has an attribute language, which holds his preferred locale. At the same time, pages have also a :locale controlled by a menu dropdown list.

I support a password_reset action via a mail that is sent to the user. When the User language is :he and the pages locale is :en the mail sent is garaged. Seems like an issue on encoding. Any ideas?

Here are the relevant code pieces:

```
app/mailers/application.rb:
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def password_reset(user)
  @user = user
  I18n.with_locale(@user.language) do
    mail(
      to:      @user.email,
      subject: I18n.t('user_mailer.reset_password.subject')
    )
  end
end

app/views/user_mailer/password_reset.html.erb:
<h1><%= t('user_mailer.reset_password.subject') %></h1>
<p><%= t('user_mailer.reset_password.content') %></p>
<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, 
                                                  locale: @user.language,
                                                  email: @user.email) %>
<p><%= t('user_mailer.reset_password.message') %></p>
```

There is an identical :he layout (app/views/user_mailer/password_reset.he.html.erb)

The translations are kept in (below except is from the :en file:

```
config/locales/user_mailer.{en|he}.yml:
en:
  user_mailer:
    reset_password:
     subject:  "Password Reset"
     greeting: "Hi %{name},"
     content:  "To reset your password click the link below"
     message:  "This link will expire in two hours."
```

The garbage that I get follows (excerpt from the server logs:

```
----==_mimepart_622c60f27661a_11a8ca1c473e3
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

16LXnCDXnteg16og15zXl9eT16kg15DXqiDXlNeh15nXodee15AsINeZ16kg
15zXnNeX15XXpSDXotecINeU15zXmdeg16cg15TXntem15XXqNejOg0KDQpo
dHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMDAvaGUvcGFzc3dvcmRfcmVzZXRzL2dMWWZn
TnJtTGR3VHlKR3ZYZGF6b3cvZWRpdD9lbWFpbD1nLm1hdGlzc2glNDBnbWFp
bC5jb20NCg0K15TXnNeZ16DXpyDXmdek16fXoiDXkdeq15XXmiDXqdei16rX
```

This drags on and on...

Answer (score 0):

After deployment to production, it turned out that the issue was actually encoding. On production, the mails are actually sent and they come in the proper encoding (and  language).

So, be careful with languages which are not based on ASCII but need UTF-8 encodings. They will not appear properly in Rails (dev) logs.